# equilibrium points of an differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to find the equilibrium points of this differential equation:

$y'(t)=ay(1-y)-by$

i have found that $y=\frac{(a-b)}{a }$makes $y'(t)=0$  but i don't know if $y'(t)=0$ is also an equilibrium solution

thanks for the help!

Comment: yes your approach is true . you can calculate$ y''$ to find out type of  equilibrium points (sink or source) if $y''(x_e)<0 then $x_e$is absorb point and  $y''(x_e).0 then $x_e$is source  point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any value of $y$ that makes $y'=0$ is an equilibrium point.  If $ay(1-y)-by=0$ then either $y=0$ or $a(1-y)-b=0$.  The latter implies $y=(a-b)/a$.  So $0$ and $(a-b)/a$ are both equilibrium points, and there are no others.

Answer (score 1):

An equilibrium solution is a constant solution to a differential equation. If you draw a [**slope field**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_field), the equilibrium solution is a horizontal line . So if you'd like to find the equilibrium solution for an OE, you have to put the OE equal to zero and solving for the variable value. Exactly what @Micheal did in details.

Comment: Nice overview of the problem and approach to solving it +1